# PHP - retrieving all the data corresponding to a radio button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I am using php and have less experience in it. I am displaying data in a table, which has a radio button at the start of each row. I want to retrieve all the data that is present in the row corresponding to the radio button I check. 
Here is something what I have done till now:

```html
<form name="test" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>book_id</th>
                <th>card no</th>
                <th>fname</th>
                <th>lname</th>
            </tr>
```

```
<?php
            $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            if ($conn) {
                mysql_select_db("library");
            } else {
                echo 'no such database';
            }

$query_test = "select book_id2,a.card_no,fname,lname from book_loans a, borrower b where a.card_no = b.card_no ";

            $result = mysql_query($query_test);

            if ($result === FALSE) {
                mysql_error();
            } else {

                while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='test'></td>";
                   echo "<td>" .$rows['book_id2']. "</td>";
                   echo "<td>" .$rows['card_no']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$rows['fname']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$rows['lname']. "</td>";

                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }

       ?>
```

```html
 <input type="submit" name="test_val" value="submit"/>
        </table>
        </form>
```

Here I want to print the data i.e. book_id, card_no, fname, lname as the submit button is clicked:

```
<?php

if($_POST)
            {
                if(isset($_POST['test_val']))
                {
                 // TO PRINT THE DATA CORRESPONDING TO THE RADIO BUTTON      
                }
            }
?>
```

Comment: You can do it by putting table in a form and on click radio button call a javascript function to submit form and then display according to posted data or can use ajax requests for each click

Answer (score 2):

Add hidden input fields in each of the `<td>` rows.  For example:

```
echo "<td>".$rows['book_id2']."</td><input type='hidden' name ='book_id2' value='".$rows['book_id2']."' />";
```

I've tried writing the JavaScript but this is much easier in JQuery.  Add these scripts before the end of the closing `</body>` tag.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    var toggleInput = function(){
        $('input[type=hidden]').prop('disabled', true);
        var selection = $('input:checked').eq(0);
            selection.parent().parent().find('input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
               $(this).prop('disabled',false);
            });
        }
        $(form).on('submit',toggleInput);
 </script>
```

[JQuery](https://jquery.com/) is used a lot in manipulating the DOM like this.  It cuts out a lot of the repetition that can be seen in JavaScript.  Although if it is easier to do something with just JavaScript, then do it!

On form submission, we're disabling all hidden elements.  Then we find the active radio box, and activate the hidden elements corresponding to the radio box.

This is one solution and might need to be tweaked.  JavaScript and JQuery are your friends for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the data as the value attribute of your radio button

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='test' value='".$rows['book_id2']." ".$rows['card_no']." ".$rows['fname']." ".$rows['lname']."'>";
```

Then the name of the post variable will be the name of the radio button

```
if(isset($_POST['test']))
{
    echo $_POST['test'];
}
```

Another example, to access individual values:

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='test' value='".addslashes( json_encode($rows) )."'>";

if(isset($_POST['test']))
{
    $result = json_decode( stripslashes($_POST['test']) ) ;
    echo $result->book_id2;
    echo $result->card_no;
    echo $result->fname;
    echo $result->lname;
}
```

Comment: it worked thank you. can you tell me if there is any way i can get the individual value from the 'test' i.e. book_id, card_no etc. for further use.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this:

1. Create a hidden textarea (which will be holding data corresponding to the radio button)
2. Assign a dynamic id (unique) to the `<tr>` and `<td>` and once the respective radio button is clicked, create JS function which will capture all the data w.r.t the row and if a new radio is clicked, it will clear out the old data and replaces it with new.
3. Submit the data and you can capture that required data.

> Functions you wil require (Inbuilt and User Defined):

1   `$( "#tr_unique td_unique" )[.text()][1]; // text() Since you are storing data in td else it would be val()` 
2 `insertData(number){`
`// Here number is the row # through which you'll track corresponding data` 
 `}` 
3 `$( "#hidden_textarea" )[.val][1]('data')`

See, if that helps.